# User Authorization with CanCan:  NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, authorization, cancan

Im using CanCan for authorization in my app. I currently have all of each users information stored at /users/2 or users/3 or /users/4 and so on.

My problem is that when a user logs in they can just amend the URL and see other users sensitive content. How can I use CanCan to prevent a user (say users/2) from seeing (users/3) ?

When I add "load_and_authorize_resource" to my users controller I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#show

undefined method `user_id' for #<User:0x007fee61e90b90>
```

Models

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
      can :access, :rails_admin
      can :dashboard 
    else
      can :manage, User, :user_id => user.id
    end
```

Controllers

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      protect_from_forgery

      rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
        redirect_to root_path, :alert => exception.message
      end


class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

   def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @date = params[:month] ? Date.parse("#{params[:month]}-01") : Date.today
    @occasions = @user.occasions.page(params[:page]).per(5)
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to put `load_and_authorize_resource` at the top of your `UsersController`?

Comment: figured it out.. just needed to change "can :manage, User, :user_id == user" to lowercase u "can :manage, user, :user_id == user"

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use

```
can :manage, User, :id => user.id
```

So they can manage the record of a User when the id of the user is the same as the I'd of the current user - that is themselves? The User class doesn't have a user_id, which is why it wasn't working to start with.

Comment: I agree with this answer. It was the first thing that I noticed as well.